# XML Validation : the element 'order' in namespace 'ordersSchema' has invalid child element 'deliveryAddress'

Tags: xml, validation, namespaces, parent-child

i have to make a XSD file that validate's a certain XML file i think am on good path but i got stuck i have been looking at my code for days and got lost so now am looking for some one that can look at my code with new view , i included my Schema where i need to change the code

The error i get in visual studio :Warning   1   The element 'orders' in namespace 'OrdersSchema' has invalid child element 'order' in namespace 'OrdersSchema'. List of possible elements expected: 'order'.    Desktop\xml\Orders.Valid.01.xml 3   4   Miscellaneous Files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:os="OrdersSchema"
        targetNamespace="OrdersSchema"
        elementFormDefault="unqualified"
        attributeFormDefault="qualified">
  <element name="orders"    type="os:orders"/>
  <complexType name="orders">
    <sequence>
      <element name="order" type="os:order" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
  <complexType name="order">
    <sequence>
      <element name="deliveryAddress">
        <complexType>
          <sequence>
            <element name='line1' type='os:lineType'/>
            <element name='line2' type='os:lineType'/>
            <element name='line3' type='os:lineType'/>
            <element name='line4' type='os:lineType' minOccurs='0'/>
          </sequence>
          <attribute name="orderId" type="string" use="required" >
          </attribute>
          <attribute name="type" type="os:typeType" use="required"/>
        </complexType>
        <unique name="uniqueOrderIdPerOrder">
          <selector xpath="os:order"/>
          <field xpath="orderId"/>
        </unique>
      </element>
      <element name='items'>
        <complexType>
          <attribute name='productId' type='os:productIdType'/>
          <attribute name='quantity'>
            <simpleType>
              <restriction base='positiveInteger'>
              </restriction>
            </simpleType>
          </attribute>
        </complexType>
      </element>
      <element name='note' minOccurs='0' type='string'/>
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
  <simpleType name='lineType'>
    <restriction base='string'>
      <minLength value='1'/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>
  <simpleType name='typeType'>
    <restriction base='string'>
      <enumeration value='standard'/>
      <enumeration value='express'/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>
  <simpleType name='productIdType'>
    <restriction base='string'>
      <pattern value='(?i)p[-\s](150|1[0-4][0-9]|[[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\.[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]'/>
      <pattern value='A...+[$XYZ]\b'/>
    </restriction>
  </simpleType>    
</schema>
```

This is the XML file if any one is willing to try it out him self

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<os:orders xmlns:os="OrdersSchema">
<os:order orderId="ord0001" type="standard">
<deliveryAddress>
  <line1>5, Elmstreet</line1>
  <line2>90210 Beverly Hills</line2>
  <line3>California</line3>
</deliveryAddress>
<items>
  <item productId="P 150.aabaac" quantity="5" />
</items>
<note>Deliver after 5 pm.</note>
</os:order>
<os:order orderId="ord0003" type="express">
<deliveryAddress>
  <line1>Voskenslaan 30</line1>
  <line2>BE9000 Gent</line2>
  <line3>Oost-Vlaanderen</line3>
  <line4>Belgium</line4>
</deliveryAddress>
<items>
  <item productId="A3546sdfsdf6546sdf654Z" quantity="10" />
  <item productId="p 149.SLKDOZ" quantity="5" />
  <item productId="P 100.xcvZEr" quantity="15" />
</items>
</os:order>
<os:order orderId="ord0002" type="express">
<deliveryAddress>
  <line1>Voskenslaan 32</line1>
  <line2>BE9000 Gent</line2>
  <line3>Oost-Vlaanderen</line3>
  <line4>Belgium</line4>
</deliveryAddress>
<items>
  <item productId="P-99.ruioze" quantity="15" />
  <item productId="A123qze46548X" quantity="50" />
  <item productId="P 1.sqmfze" quantity="1" />
  <item productId="AoknY" quantity="20" />
</items>
<note>This is <b>very urgent</b> !</note>
</os:order>
</os:orders>
```

Comment: The error message is saying that the validator is expecting an `orderAdress` element (<-- note the misspelling), but it is spelled correctly in the XSD you posted here. Is your validator perhaps looking at an old version of your XSD file where `orderAddress` was misspelled? That's the only explanation I can think of, since `orderAdress` doesn't appear anywhere in your XSD.

Comment: hello, i try'ed again today i i got the error copy'ed now i think i made the spelling error in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular error you are seeing is happening because:

- You have `elementFormDefault="unqualified"` in the `<schema>` element (this is the default value)
- All of your elements except for `orders` are declared within other structures in the XSD (inside other types or elements).

The result is that `orders` is the only element in the `OrdersSchema` namespace, and the rest have no namespace.

The [rules for determining the namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element) of an element declared in an XSD are as follows:

- If it is a top-level `<element>` (i.e. it is immediately inside the `<schema>` element), then its namespace is the URI specified in `targetNamespace`.
- For non-top-level `<elements>`:

  - If it has a `form` attribute with the value `qualified`, then its namespace is the URI specified in `targetNamespace`.
  - If it has no `form` attribute, and the `<schema>` element has an `elementFormDefault` attribute with the value `qualified`, then its namespace is the URI specified in `targetNamespace`
  - Otherwise it has no namespace.

Probably the best course of action for you is to change `elementFormDefault` to `qualified`. Once you do that, you'll see new errors because now *all* of your elements will have a namespace and you don't have prefixes on anything but `orders` and `order`, but hopefully this gives you the push you need in order to figure the rest out.

Comment: And likewise, you probably _don't_ want `attributeFormDefault="qualified"` as that would mean you need to name your attributes like `os:orderId` instead of just `orderId`.